# Integrate a facebook messenger bot with database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook, bots, database

I am creating a facebook bot and this bot has to store responses in a database. What databases can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any database you are comfortable with. The language or framework you use to develop the bot may also influence the kind of database you end up using, for example you're very likely going to use mongodb if you decide to build your bot in node and mysql for php etc.

The choice is up to you.